# JMeter- POST Json Request does it simulate or actually post data in UI?

Tags: post, jmeter, simulate

I know it is a basic Question. Does a POST Json Request for update in User interface actually Post data in to database or just simulates the load for Post data without actually posting in database. But can someone please clarify

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP Post request with the mandatory body (can be parameters, JSON, XML etc.), is intended to `upload the data into server` (upload images, Sign Up etc.), or to `post data which server wants` (to validate Sign in etc., not necessarily insert into the DB). So, it is basically how Server treats the data and the purpose.

If server puts the received data into the database, when performed the action using the browser, then the `same operation expected` when performed through JMeter also irrespective of the type of body data (JSON, XML etc). So, If you post the JSON data, it must be inserted into DB.

In DB, One thing to note is that server, either can directly dump the JSON data as JSON type itself or parse the JSON data and take the required values and store them in the Database. It depends on how the server is implemented.

So, how the server is implemented, it should behave the same way, whether you send the request from the browser or JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on implementation. From JMeter's perspective API endpoint is yet another URL, JMeter sends a request to it, measures time between request and response and marks result as passed or failed depending whether [HTTP Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is below 400 or not.

So it is up to **you** to check:

1. What does API endpoint actually do
2. What is correct request syntax (mandatory arguments, headers, cookies, URL parameters, whatever)
3. What is the expected result.
4. Optionally, what happens if "bad" request is being sent.

When designing a JMeter test always run it with 1-2 users and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener enabled to ensure that it does what it is supposed to be doing.

Coming back to your question: if HTTP response code is below 400, JMeter will mark sampler as successful, it won't check response body or database so I would recommend using the following test elements for confirmation:

- [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) - to check whether database was updated as a result of the request or not.
- [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) - to check that API response doesn't have errors, status code, [variables, returned from the database](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter), etc.